# Can a file know that it has downloaded itself into a file system?

Tags: windows, file, fat

Say a file is passed to me via email.I download it onto my desktop. Does this file know the difference between being on a machine's file system and floating around in email?
AFAIK, a file is just dead weight until it is clicked or executed in some way to come alive. But what-if there was some setting inside of a file that could "bring it to life" as soon as it knows it is in some kind of a file system, doing away with the double-click et al.

Comment: the file is always on a machine's file system, whether that machine is a desktop computer, an email server or otherwise

Comment: I don't understand the question. A file doesn't know anything; it's just a collection of bytes, nothing more. A *process* running on a computer might "know" the location of a file. Can you elaborate on what you are asking?

Comment: A file is just a sequence of bits -- ones and zeros. Also, nothing inside of a computer "knows" anything or even remotely approaches the complexity of something that's "alive". A computer is relatively simple compared to a sentient organism. It's just a state machine -- just logic gates, registers, and RAM stepping through a sequence of instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't have thought so. Attachments usually sit within a temp files / temp internet files location, which is where they're stored when you open direct from an attachment.

Saving an attachment to your desktop would be seen as a separate file altogether.

I don't know if Outlook (or any other mail client) inherently store a "Saved Attachment" flag against an e-mail or not. I guess it wouldn't be impossible for an online client to know if a file has been downloaded but again, I'm not 100% certain if that is something that is used.